# How to add dynamic basePath in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating an app where I want to put groupID before the actual URL, something like this 'https://web-site.com/1/tasks'. There is a basePath described in nextJs docs however it is created at build time and can't be changed. My current project has a lot of routing so I'll have to either manually add ${groupID} to all my Link components or create a decorator for Link. So I was wondering if there is a best practice for this kind of thing in NextJs?

Code for some context:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Example = () => {
    const {query} = useRouter()
    return(
        <Link href={`${query.groupID}/tasks`} />
    )
}
```

ps. if you think that my initial approach is bad I'm also interested in any other advice.

Comment: can you give us the code you've tried

Comment: @JoeWarner I'll update my post and include some code that will explain the approaches I have in my mind currently

Comment: Isn't a [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) more suitable for this use case?

Comment: @juliomalves I'm using dynamic routing. Now I need a way to direct my Links with dynamic id for these routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems you don't need to `basePath`, you can define a secondary Link component that takes `groupID` as a prop and puts that before the href, something like this pseudocode:

```
const BlahBlahLink = ({groupId, href}) => <Link href={groupId + href} />
```

if `groupId` is a global state/value, you could read that from cookies (or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)), e.g:

```
const BlahBlahLink = ({ href }) => {
  const [groupId] = useContenxt(BlahBlahContext);

  return <Link href={groupId + href} />;
};
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I initially wanted to do however I thought that nextJs might have some built-in method of which I'm unaware. Otherwise, this approach is the best for this case and should be considered a valid answer. Thank you!